# How to convert string in to decimal values in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-spinner

I am writing an application in which alcohol consumption is calculated. The formula gives male and females a different decimal value. I have created a spinner for this. Here is the spinner written in java.

```
Spinner genderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Genderspinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DrinksActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gender));
        myAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        genderSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter4);
```

Here is the string array in the spinner. Here is the XML code.

```
<string-array name="gender">
        <item>M</item> <!--0.68-->
        <item>F</item> <!--0.55-->
    </string-array>
```

I want to assign the decimal values to M(male) as 0.68 and F(female) as 0.55 so that I can carry out a calculation with the selected item. I would like to know how to do this in java code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` which will be called when the user changes the item in the drop-down. Then you can find out what the selected item is "M" or "F" and based on that you can just assign the correct factor in the code.

Example:

```
if "M".equals(selectedItem) { 
    dFactor = 0.68
} else {
    dFactor = 0.55
}
```

here is a full example how to use the `onItemSelectedListener`:
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/03/android-spinner-arrayadapter.html